# Getting attachment file size in outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive emails and would like to save size of attachment in Excel sheet.

I can save size of email but I can't get size of attachment.

I looked up attachment.Size Property in MSDN, but it doesn't work. Could you please take a loop my for loop? I've attached my code below. I appreciate it if anyone would help.

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim OutlookMail As Variant

Dim Folder As MAPIFolder

Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient

Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date

Dim i As Integer

Dim sFilter As String
Dim sFilterLower As String
Dim sFilterUpper As String
Dim sFilterSender As String



'========================================================
'access to shared mailbox to get items
'========================================================

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olShareName = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("teammailbox@example.ca")
Set Folder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folders("Subfolder1").Folders("Subfolder2")
Set olItems = Folder.Items


dStart = Range("From_Date").Value
dEnd = Range("To_Date").Value


'========================================================
'Conditions for restrict to get items specificed date
'========================================================

sFilterLower = "[ReceivedTime] >  '" & Format(dStart, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sFilterUpper = "[ReceivedTime] <  '" & Format(dEnd, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sFilterSender = "[SenderName] = ""jon.doe@example.com"""


'========================================================
'Restrict emails followed by above conditions
'========================================================

Set myItems = olItems.Restrict(sFilterLower)
Set myItems = myItems.Restrict(sFilterUpper)
Set myItems = myItems.Restrict(sFilterSender)


'========================================================
'items(emails) display in worksheets
'========================================================

i = 1

For Each myItem In myItems

     MsgBox myItem.Attachments.Size

     Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = myItem.Subject
     Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = Format(myItem.ReceivedTime, "h:nn")
     Range("eMail_size").Offset(i, 0).Value = myItem.Size

     i = i + 1

Next myItem

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing


End Sub

Sub sbClearCellsOnlyData()
    Rows("5:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VBEditor has a great built-in tool for debugging. If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, while selecting the `myItem` text with your mouse cursor you would be able to see it. It is called "Local Window" (or in German - "überwachungsausdrücke")

Long stroy short, give it a try like this in the code:

```
MsgBox myItem.Attachments.Item(1).Size
```

Instead of:

```
MsgBox myItem.Attachments.Size
```

Before doing this, it is a good idea to see whether the attachment exists:

`If myItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've already knew about Local window and it doesn't show attachment's size. I  tried what you suggested but It doesn't get size. I actually can see number but It's not file size.

Comment: I just realized that it's converting KB -> MB or something like that.
I get random number and I multiple by 1024. It's attachments size.

Answer (score 2):

`Attachment.Size` property is not the size of the file blob - it is the size of the attachment record in the message store, which includes the attachment data, file name, and various other MAPI properties.

If you only want the file data, you can either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) to open the blob (`PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN`) as IStream and call `IStream::Stat`. If you are limited to using the Outlook Object Model only, the only workaround is saving the attachment as file (`Attachment.SaveAsFile`) and then retrieving the file size.

Answer (score 0):

I got hint from @Vityata and my below code is fixed and it works now.

```
For Each myItem In myItems

     Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = myItem.Subject
     Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = Format(myItem.ReceivedTime, "h:nn")

     If myItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
     Range("eMail_size").Offset(i, 0).Value = myItem.Attachments.Item(1).Size / 1024  'convert to 3 digits (KB)

     Else
     Range("eMail_size").Offset(i, 0).Value = "No attached file"

     End If

  i = i + 1

Next myItem
```